# How to setup Tensorboard in Kaggle Kernels (or in Colab with TF2) ? (in order to tune hyperparameters)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard, kaggle

I have troubles setting up Tensorboard in a Kaggle Kernel. I'm trying to optimize the hyperparameters of my CNN using Tensorboard callback, but I'm struggling, as in the Kaggle Kernel, I don't know how to get the Tensorboard interface, even though it seems to be configured and this (https://www.kaggle.com/aagundez/using-tensorboard-in-kaggle-kernels) has not helped me at all, as it results in an error 404.

In Colab, instead, when updating tensorflow to tf2, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1). Contents of stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 8, in <module>     sys.exit(run_main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 59, in run_main     default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 110, in get_dynamic_plugins     for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 110, in <listcomp>     for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2442, in load     self.require(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2465, in require     items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve     raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (grpcio 1.15.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('grpcio>=1.24.3'))
```

And I don't know how to workaround it. So, I really don't know what to do.
Do you have any advice? Can I optimize my hyperparameters in other ways (scikit-learn, talos...) by using generators and flow_from_directory (so no x_train, y_train...) or transform it in the other format easily?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the issue you observe in Colab?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you use Tensorboard in Colab with TF2

[get_start.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/get_started.ipynb)

The key part is

```py
%tensorflow_version 2.x
%load_ext tensorboard
# train and collect logs then call tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir logs/fit
```